Maximum recursive updates exceeded in Vue when formatting response from API call
I've been trying to debug a Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component error message.
Basically, I have component1 making an API call and then passing the response to component2 as a prop
COMPONENT1:
const form = ref(null)
const datatable = ref({})
const rowData = ref([])
onMounted(async () => {
  let response = await retrieveData(store.id, store.module)
  form.value = response.renderForm
  rowData.value = response.rowData
});

<ChildComponent :render-form="form" :datatable-rows="rowData"/>
COMPONENT2:
<Datatable :rows=props.datatableRows/>
API:

export const retrieveData = async (id) => {
  let response = await apiGET(URL)
  response.data.rowData.forEach(row, index, rows) => {
    let jsonRow = JSON.parse(row)
    delete jsonRow.Field1
    delete jsonRow.Field2
    rows[index] = jsonRow
  });

  return response.data
}

Everything works as expected but when I do some data formatting inside my API call (everything inside the for each loop) that's when I am seeing the maximum recursive calls problem.
Any insight appreciated, thank you.

There is an infinite loop somewhere in your code, check for some watch or alike lifecycle.

Please [edit] your question to show an example of the type of code that causes the problem

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You're modifying an array you're iterating, but this cannot cause the error. That there's syntax error .forEach(row, index, rows)  suggests the actual code may differ from the one you posted
